# Getting ERROR_SHARING_VOILATION error on CFile::Open method call

Tags: file-io, bitmap, gdi+

I load a png icon file at start of my program using this following code:

```
if (NULL == m_pImage) {
        Bitmap *pImage = new Bitmap(T2W(filePath));
        if (size == kSmallIconSize) {
            m_pImage = static_cast<Bitmap *>(pImage->GetThumbnailImage(size, size));
        } else {
            m_pImage = pImage;
        }
        if (m_pImage->GetLastStatus() == Ok) 
            m_resID = index;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
```

Then on some event, I try to open the same file with

```
CFile file;
if (TRUE == file.Open(filePath, CFile::modeRead))
```

but it fails to open the file and `GetLastError()` returns 32 which means

> ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION

How can I fix this?

**Update:**

Just to make sure its the "Bitmap loading" code thats causing the ERROR, I tried CFile::Open immediately after that and confirmed it.

Why is `Bitmap::Bitmap(WCHAR *pFilePath)` not sharing the file or letting it go once loaded..?

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675):

[image: MSDN1]

And the workaround:

[image: MSDN2]

Comment: @user2432627 your questions was *"Why is Bitmap::Bitmap(WCHAR *pFilePath) not sharing the file or letting it go once loaded..?"*, which is what I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pImage` variable has not been deallocated, so the file is still in use.

Try opening the file using the `CFile::shareDenyNone` flag:

```
if (TRUE == file.Open(filePath, CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareDenyNone))
```